# grep with special expressions

Tags: grep, ls, gnome-terminal

I have some binaries and some `.c` extension files in my directory.

Here the output using `ls`

> arrays.c  basic0  basic0.c  fromfb  fromfb.c  oute  oute.c  segmen.c 
>   simp  simp.c

Here i want to filter binary files only , so I use

```
ls |grep -v .c
```

This command list all files, Then using `grep` I get files, except those file not ending with .c

What I expect is

```
basic0
fromfb
oute
simp
```

But What i got

```
fromfb
oute
simp
```

basic0 binary file missing. What is the problem with this?

Comment: try `ls | grep -v "\.c"` ("\." escapes dot sign)

Comment: @Wildcard , iam not like to finding binary files, I just want to why grep behave like this.So this not duplication :)

Comment: ``ls | grep`` is almost always not what you want. You probably want ``find``.

Comment: this question is more about grep than binaries. I'll vote Leave Open.

Comment: Sounds like we have an "X" and a "Y" problem; a confusion regarding grep, and a desire to "find binary files only"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per `man grep`

> The period . matches any single character.

thus `grep .c` match any character followed by `c`

You might be looking for `grep -v \.c` or better `grep -v '\.c$'`

where

- `\.` escape special meaning of .
- `c`
- `$` end of line (when piped to ls output one file name par line)

as suggested by wildcard, you can also use `grep -vF .c` The `-F` flag tells grep to use arg as simple string, not regular expression.

Comment: Or just `grep -F .c` to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dot sign with "\.". Try with `ls | grep -v "\.c$"`. Executing `grep -v .c` means any record that does not contain the charater **c**  preceded by another character

Comment: @EricRenouf thank you, just edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

#### man

`man grep` tells us that

> The period . matches any single character.

This means that `.c` matches any single character followed by a *c*. Since you haven't anchored your expression, this matches any string that contains any character followed by a *c*.

Let's test that. What if we don't use the `-v` flag?

#### test

Let's see. First, we set up a test

```
~ $ mkdir test
~ $ cd test
~/test $ touch arrays.c
~/test $ touch basic0
~/test $ touch basic0.c
~/test $ touch fromfb
~/test $ touch fromfb.c
~/test $ touch oute
~/test $ touch oute.c
~/test $ touch segmen.c
~/test $ touch simp
~/test $ touch simp.c
~/test $ ls
arrays.c  basic0.c  fromfb.c  oute.c    simp
basic0    fromfb    oute      segmen.c  simp.c
```

Then we test `ls | grep .c`:

```
~/test $ ls|grep .c
arrays.c
basic0
basic0.c
fromfb.c
oute.c
segmen.c
simp.c
```

As you can see, not only do the intended C sources match, but the binary file `basic0` matches as well. The *i* is matched by the `.` and the *c* is matched by (no surprise here) the `c`.

#### solution

You want to match C sources to exclude them. These files end with *.c*, so we tell grep to match those.

```
~/test $ ls|grep "\.c$"
arrays.c
basic0.c
fromfb.c
oute.c
segmen.c
simp.c
```

We've done two things here. First, we've escaped the dot, to make it a *literal dot* instead of "any single character". But this would still match a file called `foo.c.bar` which may or may not be your goal.
Assuming it's not, we've also anchored the c to be the last character. Now you're matching the strings that *end* with a dot and a *c*.

Reapplying `-v` is left as an exercise for the reader.